# Grinding brakes

Tags: brakes

Just recently (in last few months) got all breaks redone, also new summers put on. Did not get a wheel alignment done as shop refused due to tie rods worn and something else (can't remember exactly) needed fixing/replacing...fast forward to today...put on brakes at stop sign (going slow so didn't jam on) and heard grinding noise. Tried a couple other times and did not grind but vehicle started squeaking when in drive. Next stop sign started grinding very bad and then continued to grind even in drive for awhile...doesn't happen every time brakes are applied though. I 'was' thinking rock in brake drum but 
Had friend look who said back rotor screwed and needs new brakes. 
This soon after having them replaced would it possibly be indirectly due to no alignment being done or...?

Comment: any chance you were driving around with the parking brake set?

Comment: No, parking brake was not set

Comment: it would be good to know exactly what was done at the last service.

Answer (score 1):

No, disc rotor wear has absolutely nothing to do with wheel alignment. They are unrelated issues.

I assume when you said you had brakes  done a few months ago they replaced the brake pads and not the rotor. If they were badly worn they should have advised you at the time.